Django: Ignore trans strings which are already translated in app directory
I use django-allauth as a third partie package in my Django project.
I copied some templates from django-allauth into my template directory to modify the layout. But I did not touch the translation strings!
After running makemessages this strings appears in my .po file even though it is translated in the app directory for django-allauth. (To manage my translations I use Weblate.)
How can I stop this behavior? This is blowing up my .po file and is confusing the translators, because we have to notify them not to touch this string.
Can I create a list of "msgid" which will ignore some strings?

In the meanwhile I found a very easy to use was. I just created my own templatetag which will be ignored from makemeassge.
register = template.Library()
from django.templatetags.i18n import do_block_translate, do_translate

register.tag('ignore_blocktrans', do_block_translate)
register.tag('ignore_trans', do_translate)

That way, you just add ignore_trans or ignore_blocktrans to stick to the translation from the package.
